# Calculate $\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How to properly calculate it.

Factor of $(x^5-7)$ is $(x-7^{1/5})(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$

1. I don't know if these degree two polynomials are irreducible or not.
2. Let us say they are irreducible. Then can we say by chinese remainder theorem that  $$\mathbb R[x]/(x^5-7)\cong \mathbb {R\times C\times C}\cong \mathbb R^5$$ as both $\mathbb R$-modules and $\mathbb R[x]$-modules?

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive 5th root of unity. Your two polynomials are $(x-\zeta\sqrt[5]{7})(x-\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{7})$ and $(x-\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{7})(x-\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{7})$, which are irreducible as their roots are pairs of non-real complex numbers interchanged by conjugation.
2. As $\Bbb R$-modules, any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, so all your isomorphisms are valid. As $\Bbb R[x]$-modules, one can apply [the structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain#Primary_decomposition) to see that $\Bbb R[x]/(x^5-7)$ is isomorphic to $$\Bbb R[x]/(x-\sqrt[5]{7}) \oplus \Bbb R[x]/((x-\zeta\sqrt[5]{7})(x-\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{7})))\oplus \Bbb R[x]/((x-\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{7})(x-\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{7}))$$ which is isomorphic as $\Bbb R[x]$-modules to $\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb C\oplus \Bbb C$ with $x$ acting as one of the roots of the given polynomials on each factor. It cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb R^5$ as an $\Bbb R[x]$-module, though.